# Problema con desplazamiento de contenedor

Tags: css, reactjs

estoy creando un tipo de scroll que cuando el user scrollea el sitio hacia abajo y pasa por la seccion con 3 divs (adjunto foto) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] despues de pasar por la posicion del primero se añade al state una clase que se llama en el css y desplaza el div verde hacia arriba(adjunto foto 2)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y si scrolleo hacia abajo el contendor verde vuelve a su posicion inicial.
El problema con esto es que si sigo scrolleando sobre el div verde, deberia subir tambien el div de color rosado, pero de alguna forma eso no sucede. Revise el condicional del metodo `handleScroll` y este siempre evalua true despues de que scrolleo desde cierto punto. Lo que intento es que despues de scrollear sobre el verde suba el rosado, manteniendo el verde y el comportamiento de los 2 anteriores arriba.

```
    // React
    import React from 'react';

    // Styles
    import './style.sass';

    class FourthSection extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                newClass: ''
            }

            this.panelOne = React.createRef();
            this.panelTwo = React.createRef();
            this.panelThree = React.createRef();
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            let panelOnePos = this.panelOne.current.offsetTop - 500;
            let panelTwoPos = this.panelTwo.current.offsetTop - 500;
            let panelThreePos = this.panelThree.current.offsetTop; 

            
            window.addEventListener('scroll', e => this.handleScroll(panelOnePos, panelTwoPos, panelThreePos, e))
        }

        handleScroll = (panelOnePos, panelTwoPos, panelThreePos, e) => {
            let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
            console.log('current scroll ', currentScrollPos);
            console.log('current panelOnePos ', panelOnePos)
            console.log('current panelTwoPos ', panelTwoPos)

            if((currentScrollPos >= panelOnePos)) {
                console.log('entro I')
                this.setState({
                    newClass: 'movingContainer'
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    newClass: ''
                })
            }

            if(currentScrollPos >= panelTwoPos) {
                this.setState({
                    newClass: 'movingContainer'
                })
            }


        }
        
        

        render() {

            return(
                <div className="container-overlay" >
                <div class="panel panel-one" ref={this.panelOne}>
                    <div class="panel-inner">
                        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                        <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class={`panel panel-two ${this.state.newClass}`} ref={this.panelTwo}>
                    <div class="panel-inner">
                        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                        <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class={`panel panel-three ${this.state.newClass}`} ref={this.panelThree}>
                    <div class="panel-inner">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                        <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default FourthSection;
```

adjunto el css tambien:

```
    .container-overlay
        & > .panel-one
            position: relative
            background: red
            transition-timing-function: ease-out
            transition: 0.25s
            height: 300px
            width: 100%
            position: static

        & > .panel-two
            position: relative
            margin-top: -20px
            transition-timing-function: ease-out
            transition: 0.25s
            background: green
            height: 300px
            width: 100%

        & > .panel-three
            position: relative
            margin-top: -20px
            transition-timing-function: ease-out
            transition: 0.25s
            background: pink
            height: 300px
            width: 100%

    .movingContainer
        position: fixed
        transition-timing-function: ease-out
        transition: 0.25s
        transform: translateY(-250px)
        width: auto
```

Comment: No pude emular el problema de mi lado, cuando hago scroll hacia abajo el div rosa se sube y tapa al verde; luego, si subo, ya no hay scroll. ¿El `sass`que proporcionaste  esta completo? Otro detalle es que hay  atributos `class` en los `div`, me parece que debería se `className`, saludos